# How do I insert content fields above title in a content type template?

Tags: theming, entities, nodes, 7

While customizing `node--mycontenttype.tpl.php` full view, I wanted to insert a couple of fields above the main page title. Can this be done in `node--mycontenttype.tpl.php`? or should I step up into the `page--whetever` level of suggestions?

This if:

```
<?php if (!$page): ?>
```

seems to never be true for that full view I'm using. I'm afraid I don't understand this flag enough.
Any hints, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use the page template instead of node template so you can add fields before the node title.
page--content-type.tpl.php